# shell script variable type is fixed by the first data type in if-statement?

Tags: shell

When using the following script, there is always an error when I set X=hello or other type except interger.
I would like to know whether the type of X is fixed by the first time if condition or not?

```
X=hello
[ $X -ne 0 ] && echo "X isn't zero" || echo "X is zero"
[ -f $X ] && echo "X is a file" || echo "X is not a file"
[ -n $X ] && echo "X is of non-zero length" || \
  echo "X is of zero length"
```

The result is:

```
[: integer expression expected: hello
X is zero
X is not a file
X is of non-zero length
```

But we know this is not what we want. How can I modify the code?

Answer (score 1):

`-ne` is an arithmetic operator and will complain if its operands aren't integers. For string comparisons use `!=`.

```
[ "$X" != 0 ] && echo "X isn't zero" || echo "X is zero"
```

Also, the quotes around `"$X"` are needed in case `$X` is empty. You want the comparison to be `[ "" != 0 ]` when it is rather than `[ != 0 ]`, which is what'll happen if `$X` is unquoted. The latter is a syntax error.

This is especially important for the third test, `[ -n "$X" ]`. If you don't have quotes `[ -n $X ]` will succeed *even when `$X` is empty!* `[ -n "" ]` will correctly return false, but `[ -n ]` will return true. Always quote variable expansions!

Comment: Thanks, here#!/bin/sh
echo -en "Please guess the magic number: "
read X
echo $X | grep "[^0-9] > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; then
  echo "Sorry, wanted a number"
else
  if [ "$X" -eq "7" ]; then
    echo "You entered the magic number!"
  fi
fi

Comment: @JohnKugelman : Just want to point out that, if X is `00`, this would output "X isn't zero". Maybe this is what the OP wants, maybe it isn't....

Comment: @user1934428 in that case `(( X+0 != 0 ))` would be a better check

Comment: @oliv : Interesting approach. I would have expected an error message with your statement, if X was set by `X=hello`, as in the origial post, but it seems to work silently. Could you explain why?

Comment: @user1934428 In an arithmetic context `((...))`, strings refer to shell variables. `hello` is not set, and default to 0. If you set `hello=2`, the answer will be different.

Comment: @oliv: An interesting and useful feature which I didn't know! Unfortunately, in the OP's context, this makes your elegant solution incorrect: As far I understand the original problem, `hello=0; X=hello` is supposed to report "X is not zero", while with your approach, it would report "X is zero".....

Comment: @oliv : On second thought: Wouldn't it with your approach be sufficient to write `(( X != 0 ))`? Since we are in arithmetic context, we don't need to explicitly add 0, since != always uses numerical inequality.